# Computing the $L$ space of a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the curve $C:x_0^n+x_1^n+x_2^n=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$, where $k$ is any field. Let $P$ be a point of degree $1$ (eg. take $P=(1,0,0))$. Consider the divisor $D=rP$, where $r\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it possible to explicitly compute the vector space $L(D)$ i.e. it's $k$-basis using only the definition of $L(\cdot )$? How does the number of basis elements depend on $r$?

Comment: Do you consider $D$ as a divisor on $C$ or on $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: $D$ is a sum of points, so it can't be a divisor on $\mathbf{P}^2$.

Comment: Dear pritam: do you know the Riemann--Roch theorem?

Comment: I guess you want $P$ to be a point on the curve, so $(1,0,0)$ is probably not a good choice.

Comment: @Asal: Ah, sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann-Roch theorem for curves gives us the formula
$$ h^0(D)-h^0(K-D) = r - g + 1, $$
where $K$ is any canonical divisor, $h^0(D)$ is the dimension of $L(D)$ and $h^0(K-D)$ is the dimension of $L(K-D)$ as vector spaces over $k$.
The integer $g=h^1(\mathcal{O}_C)$, instead, is the genus of your curve, which is probably dependent on $n$. [See below]

An useful fact is that $h^0(K-D)=0$ as soon as the degree $r$ of $D$ is bigger than the degree of $K$, which is $2g-2$.

So, if you know the genus $g$, at least you can say that if $r>2g-2$ then the dimension of $L(D)$ is given by
$$ r - g +1. $$

I know this is probably not a satisfying answer, but I hope it will put you in the right direction!

#### How to get the genus:

In the case of $C$ being smooth you can use the [degree-genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula) formula for plane curves to compute the genus:
$$ g = \frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}, $$
but I have the feeling that the smoothness of $C$ depends on the characteritic of $k$. If $C$ is not smooth than you can still say something (see the link for details).